# How to find the minimum sample size in the binomial scheme?

Tags: binomial-distribution, sample-size, likelihood-ratio, likelihood

**Background.** I am reading the paper (Kupiec, 1995).

On the Exhibit 4, you can see the minimum (incorrectly called maximal in the paper) sample size ($n$) for which the null hypothesis $p=p^*$ is reject by proportion of failures (PF) test at level $.05$.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I need compute two values in red boxs ($240$ and $49$) from the table. I have used the formula $(4)$ from the paper where the likelihood ratio test statistic is given:

$$ LR =  -2\cdot log((1-p)^{n-x}\cdot p^x)+2\cdot log((1-(x/n))^{n-x}\cdot (x/n)^x)\tag{4}$$

The formula $(4)$ looks the probability of $x=6$ failures exactly and I 
should calculate the cumulative likelihood, i.e. the probability of $6$ or fewer failures is the $$P(x<=6) = \sum_{i=0}^6 P(A_i),$$ here $P(A_i)$ is  the probability of $i$ failure.

My results and code are below:

```
n <- 255    # sample size 
p <- 0.01   # propobility of failures 

LR <- c(); 

for (x in 0:6) # number of failures in the sample
{ 
LR <- c(LR, -2*log((1-p)^(n-x)*p^x)+2*log((1-(x/n))^(n-x)*(x/n)^x))
}
LR
#[1] 5.12567129 1.23731060 0.12941267 0.07591619 0.70995239 1.85729981 3.41535753

(sum(LR))
#[1] 12.55092
```

Unfortunatly, I can't figure out how to aplly the binominal coefficient $C_n^x$ and move from the cumulative likelihood to the maximal sample size ($n$).

**Question.**  Could you please give me an idea how to derive the results from the table?

**Ref.**
Kupiec P.(1995)  [Techniques for Verifying the Accuracy of Risk Management Models](http://jod.iijournals.com/content/3/2/73). Journal of Derivatives, 3 (2), P. 73-84. 
DOI: https://doi.org/10.3905/jod.1995.407942

Comment: It should be called the minimum sample size because any larger sample size would also reject at the 0.05 level.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, I agree with you but I  used the notation from the paper.

Comment: You can show the mistake and mention that it is a mistake and change maximum to minimum in your title.

Comment: I edited your post as I have suggested. I hope you decide to keep it.